# Make company name not required WooCommerce (3rd party plugin)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I'd like to make billing company and shipping company not required in WooCommerce. For some reason the code I am using works for EVERYTHING except for the company part. **It turns out a third party plugin is making the company name required, here is the full code of that plugin:**

```html
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}


require_once('legacy_pakkelabels_shipping_main.php');

/**
 * @class   Pakkelabels_Shipping_GLS_Business_Legacy
 * @version  0.1.0
 * @author   Magnus Vejlø - Pakkelabels
 */
class Legacy_Pakkelabels_Shipping_GLS_Business extends Legacy_Pakkelabels_Shipping_Main
{

    public function __construct($instance_id = 0)
    {
        $this->id = 'legacy_pakkelabels_shipping_gls_business';
        $this->instance_id = absint($instance_id);
        $this->method_title = __('GLS Business ', 'woocommerce-pakkelabels');
        $this->method_description = __('Adds the option to ship with the GLS business to the checkout', 'woocommerce-pakkelabels');
        $this->init();
    }


    /* add the diffrent actions */
    function addActions()
    {
        //adds the shipping method to the WooCommerce
        add_filter('woocommerce_shipping_methods', array($this, 'register_shipping_method'));

        add_action('woocommerce_after_shipping_rate', array($this, 'pakkelabels_shipping_gls_business_show_below_shipping'));

        add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', array($this, 'pakkelabels_shipping_gls_business_field_process'));
    }


    function addFilters()
    {

    }


    function pakkelabels_shipping_gls_business_field_process() {

        global $woocommerce;
        $choosen_shipping_method1 = preg_replace('/\d/', '', $woocommerce->session->chosen_shipping_methods[0] );
        $choosen_shipping_method2 = preg_replace('/\d/', '', $woocommerce->session->chosen_shipping_methods );
        if((isset($_POST['ship_to_different_address']) &&  ($_POST['shipping_company'] == '' || !isset($_POST['shipping_company']))) && ($choosen_shipping_method1 == "legacy_pakkelabels_shipping_gls_business" || $choosen_shipping_method2 == "legacy_pakkelabels_shipping_gls_business")){
            if ( version_compare( $woocommerce->version, '2.1', '<' ) ) {
                $woocommerce->add_error(__('Please fill out the Shipping company', 'woocommerce-pakkelabels'));
            } else {
                wc_add_notice( __('Please fill out the Shipping company', 'woocommerce-pakkelabels') , 'error');
            }
        }
        if((!isset($_POST['ship_to_different_address']) && ($_POST['billing_company'] == '' || !isset($_POST['billing_company']))) && ($choosen_shipping_method1 == "legacy_pakkelabels_shipping_gls_business" || $choosen_shipping_method2 == "legacy_pakkelabels_shipping_gls_business")){
            if ( version_compare( $woocommerce->version, '2.1', '<' ) ) {
                $woocommerce->add_error(__('Please fill out the billing company', 'woocommerce-pakkelabels'));
            } else {
                wc_add_notice( __('Please fill out the billing company', 'woocommerce-pakkelabels') , 'error');
            }
        }
    }




    function pakkelabels_shipping_gls_business_show_below_shipping($rate){
        global $woocommerce;

        global $woocommerce;
        $choosen_shipping_method1 = preg_replace('/\d/', '', $woocommerce->session->chosen_shipping_methods[0] );
        $choosen_shipping_method2 = preg_replace('/\d/', '', $woocommerce->session->chosen_shipping_methods );
        if($choosen_shipping_method1 == "legacy_pakkelabels_shipping_gls_business" || $choosen_shipping_method2 == "legacy_pakkelabels_shipping_gls_business"){
            if($rate->method_id == 'legacy_pakkelabels_shipping_gls_business'){
                echo '<div class="gls_shipping_method_text shipping_company_required">'  . __('The company name is required.', 'woocommerce-pakkelabels').'</div>';
            }
        }
    }


    /* Register the shipping method in WooCommerce*/
    function register_shipping_method($methods)
    {
        $methods['legacy_pakkelabels_shipping_gls_business'] = 'Legacy_Pakkelabels_Shipping_GLS_Business';
        return $methods;
    }
}


$pakkelabels_GLS_Business_Legacy = new Legacy_Pakkelabels_Shipping_GLS_Business();
$pakkelabels_GLS_Business_Legacy->mainAddActions();
$pakkelabels_GLS_Business_Legacy->addActions();
$pakkelabels_GLS_Business_Legacy->addFilters();
```

The plugin used is a delivery plugin, and since we're delivering to companies it requires a company name. However, since we are a B2B store we already have these company names registered and we do not want them nor need them in the checkout. So we have hidden the company name field in WooCommerce, but no matter what code we write we cannot make it not require it to be filled out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the filter woocommerce_default_address_fields instead.

```
function modify_woocommerce_default_address_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['company']['required'] = false;

    return $fields;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'modify_woocommerce_default_address_fields', 100, 1 );
```

It states this in the [documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/) that there are specific fields that must be manipulated through this filter.

- country
- first_name
- last_name
- company
- address_1
- address_2
- city
- state
- postcode

We can use a filter to remove the notice before it is added to the array specific just to that error message.

```
function modify_woocommerce_notices( $message ) {
    if( stripos( $message, 'Please fill out the billing company' ) !== false ) {
        return '';
    }
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_error', 'modify_woocommerce_notices' );
```

I haven't tested that code but that's the general idea of how you would suppress the error and prevent the required field for the billing company.

Comment: Thank you. Tried it and while I get no error in the editor, I still get the "Please fill out the company name you are sending your package to" error.

Comment: Sounds like you have some other plugin installed that is causing this issue because by default the company name is not a required field in WooCommerce.

Comment: Hello. Yes I have edited the original post and found the code that is causing the error. Do you have any idea how to fix it in that code?

Comment: In WooCommerce that field is not mandatory.  Like I said before, you have another plugin that is making the field mandatory.  Yes I can see you have added that to your question now, so if you find out what the priority is of the hook action adding that function then you can override it with my function as set it to run after the plugin's function.  Can you paste in the action call to that function pakkelabels_shipping_gls_business_field_process.  Otherwise just set the priority of my hook to run with low priority, I will change my code above.

Comment: Ty a lot Andrew. Yes you are correct it is the third party plugin. I have attached the whole code for the part of the plugin that is causing the error.

Comment: I've added some code to my answer that will prevent the wc_notice from being added and allow you to checkout without a billing company.

Comment: This removes the other error but causes another one simply saying there was an error with the order and it could not go through. Is there any more code or info I need to provide for us to understand why this is happening? It still seems to be related to the company name that is not being filled out / in this case being asked not to

Comment: You could always just remove the fields all together using the woocommerce_default_address_fields filter to unset the fields.

Comment: How'd I do that?

Comment: There's an example in the link I shared in my answer from the official site.https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/

Comment: I tried unsetting it that way, but since it is a 3rd party plugin requiring it, it doesn't work. It just tells me that I need to fill out the company once again then. I need to somehow tell the program (code in my post) that it should not require it from woo

Comment: You haven't unset it correctly.  If you look at the error handling it will only return the error if the POST variable is set for the company.  When you remove the field that variable doesn't get set and it won't generate an error.  Change the priority of when you run the filter so it runs it later as it looks you are unsetting the field before it is even set by the plugin.

Comment: Hmm. I still haven't been able to get it right. Do you have any code that I could try and test if it would solve it? I can provide whatever info you need / existing code from the site.

Comment: Make sure you remove the error notice for both the shipping and billing companies.  Change the priority the hook I added to 999 or something high so that it runs after the error notices are set.

Comment: Excellent, straight forward when you know what you are doing ;)